# Cannot upload a new theme to CS-Cart either via web upload or SCP

Tags: ecommerce, nginx

A weird title for a weird problem...

I have an updated Arch Linux server running php 7.0.2 and mariaDB. The webserver is the beloved nginx 1.8.0-2. I've installed CS-Cart 4.3.5 Ultimate (without a license, I'm using the free one).

The problem is that I can't upload files larger that 2-3MB, CS-Cart just hangs on the process bar. Upload & post limit is set to 64M and max execution time 1 hour (it's not a production environment) in both php and php-fpm config files, phpinfo reports them perfectly fine.

Also, even if I scp the theme I want to install manually (to work around the upload problem) and try to install it via "server" location, it does nothing. The process finishes and *poof* nothing changed. I can't see the theme anywhere in the panel to apply it.

There are no errors reported anywhere. Not in the log files nor in the pages. I've tested my error log configurations and it works.

I've been banging my head against the wall...